# Trying to create a grid of buttons in SwiftUI (feels like I am missing something fundamental here...)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

so I am trying to create a grid of buttons in which each label increments by 1. E.g.:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4

5 | 6 | 7 | 8

9 | 10
```

The problem I am having is actually incrementing the number that gets displayed.

Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {
   ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
       HStack {
         ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
           Text("\(number)")
         }
       }
   }
}
```

How would I increment the number by 1 each time I go through the loop.

Comment: You don't need to increment `number`, you can just derive it from the row and column numbers that you explicitly ignored (`_ in`). If you name them `row` and `col` respectively, than you can calculate number as `4*row + col + 1`. Though I'm not familiar with SwiftUI, I suspect there's a better grid-drawing-primitive already available to you.

Comment: This may help you: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid

Comment: Oh wow I’m stupid, I was originally trying this but kept getting the incorrect values... THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like alexander-reinstate-monica says in the comment:

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach(0..<4) { row in
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<4) { col in
                Text("\(row * 4 + col + 1)")
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

This will print a grid of text views numbered from 1 to 16, sort of like this:

```
   1 2 3 4
   5 6 7 8
  9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16
```